# Function to convert array of strings into an object with the string as property name and the amount of times it appears in the array, as its value

Tags: arrays, object

I'm working on a beginner problem and i got stuck. I need to come up with a function that takes an array of strings as an argument and returns a single object with those strings, and the amount of times they are repeated in the array.
E.g.

```
function addType(arr){
}

console.log(addType(["ford","toyota","ford","nissan","ford"]) 
>>> expected output: {ford:3, toyota:1, nissan:1}
```

i can't get around to it. I got close with reduce but i get something like this instead:

```
{ ford: { ford: 3 }, toyota: { toyota: 1 }, nissan: {nissan:1 }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is your best friend. The shortes one liner I came up with is:

```
["ford","toyota","ford","nissan","ford"].reduce((acc, el) => ({...acc, [el]: acc[el]+1 || 1}), {})
```

or

```
["ford","toyota","ford","nissan","ford"].reduce((acc, el) => {acc[el] = acc[el]+1 || 1; return acc}, {})
```

### Explanation:

`acc` - acumulator, ie object that gets strings as keys. Initial empty `{}`.

`el` - current element of the array, which due to [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) becomes object's key

`++acc[el] || 1` - at first encounter of each string the expression `acc[el]` is undefined, therefore `++undefined` becomes `NaN` and the or operator `||` assignes 1 to the key. If key already exists, then increases the count by +1 (pay attention that it has to be a prefix operator `++acc[el]` and not postfix `acc[el]++`).

Exactly the same result but in less encrypted version is

```
["ford","toyota","ford","nissan","ford"].reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (acc[el]) {
    acc[el] += 1
  } else {
    acc[el] = 1
  }
  return acc;
  }, {})
```